# How do you set the linktext on url in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url

is there a way to create an action link in my controller and set the link text? Can't find an overload...

```
Url.Action("Edit", "Controller", new { id =  myId });
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a link inside your controller?

Comment: I need to create a list of links based on ids and names, just easier to do the formatting and setup in the controller rather than the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a link in controller use Helpers like this:

```
string link = HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext, System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes, "My link", "Root", "About", "Home", null, null);
```

Comment: need to do this in my controller, not view

Comment: thanks, how would i display this in my view as an actual link? Its part of a bigger string e.g. "some text : link " it gets displayed as is i.e. not a link <a href="/Controller/Edit/1">name</a>

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: [ActionLink Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492936%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Controller", new { id =  myId })
```